# Mutual information analysis for sum of Bernoulli and Gaussian

Tags: probability, analysis, statistics, information-theory, mutual-information

**Question:** I have two random variables $X\sim\text{Bernoulli}(\alpha)$ and $Y\sim\mathcal{N}(0,1)$. Is it possible to compute the mutual information $I(X;X+Y)$ analytically?

**My attempt:** By the definition of mutual information, we have
$$
I(X;X+Y)=H(X)-H(X|X+Y),
$$
where $H(X)$ can be worked out analytically but I don't know how to work out $H(X|X+Y)$.

Comment: Can you calculate $H(X+Y|X)$? Since the mutual information is symmetric, you can also aim to calculate through $H(X;X+Y) = H(X+Y) - H(X+Y|X) $.

Comment: $H(X+Y|X)$ is not well defined, but you can work with the differential entropy $h(X+Y|X)$. That said, as far as I'm aware, there is no elementary closed-form expression for the differential entropy of a mixture of two Gaussians, which is the law of $Y$, so you'll still have issues with computing $h(Y)$ analytically. There are bounds and approximations available for this, and searching for "differential entropy of mixtures of Gaussians" should bring up relevant papers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $Z=X+Y$. Notice that $Z$ has a density $f_Z$ correspoing to a gaussian mixture. Now $P(X=0|Z=z)= \frac{f_Z(z|X=0) P(X=0)}{f_Z(z)}=\frac{f_Y(z) (1-\alpha)}{f_Z(z)}=g(z)$

So $H(X|Z=z)= h_b(g(z))$ where $h_b$ is the binary entropy function. And

$$H(X|Z)= \int f_Z(z) h_b(g(z)) dz$$

I might be easier to compute instead $h(Z)-h(Z|X)$